# How to define a nested one-to-many relationship with entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many

With entity framework, I want to define a such "User" entity: each user has many friends, and the type of friend is "User". Can I define it like this?

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId {get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}

   public virtual List<User> Friends {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can , the question is do you want to separate entity or not ? If not then this works, if friends will have properties then you are better of having an entity which inherits from User.

Also, look at this for clarity on TPT [How to implement inheritance Table-Per-Type in Entity Framework 4.3 via Code First approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564972/how-to-implement-inheritance-table-per-type-in-entity-framework-4-3-via-code-fir)

In the code that you have provided, it will end up being a self referential table in the database.