# Casting From Type to Interface in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am building an ASP.NET application which will query one of three tables which capture maufacturing errors in a product. Of course each table is reflected in an EF Entity. Which table will be queried is not determined until the page is submitted and a flag is set indicating which errors to query.

Each of the three entities have many properties in common. These commonalities have been defined in an Interface and implemented by the Entities (via partial class definitions). So those partial classes look like ...

```
public partial class ProductException : IExceptionEntity { }
public partial class PartException : IExceptionEntity { }
public partial class RebuildException: IExceptionEntity { }
```

In a repository class I have defined a generic method that will allow me to query the Exception Entity that I specify. This is neccessary as the WHERE clause passed in as a parameter to the method, may contain fields that are not defined in the Interface and are specific to the individual Exception entity (product, part, and rebuild). So calling those looks like ..

```
IQueryable<ProductException> prodQuery = Repository.GetFilteredQuery<ProductException>(query, whereClause);
IQueryable<PartException> partQuery = Repository.GetFilteredQuery<PartException>(query, whereClause);
IQueryable<RebuildException> rebuildQuery = Repository.GetFilteredQuery<RebuildException>(query, whereClause);
```

At no time would the web page define more that one query, and what it would do with the results of the query is fairly similiar regardless of the results of the query, so I would like to be able to assign a variable/property that could use to access the query/results regardless of whcih entity was being queried. Something like below ...

```
    protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
         InitializeExceptionQuery();
    }


    List<IExceptionEntity> _exceptionList = null;
    public List<IExceptionEntity> ExceptionList
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(_exceptionList == null)
                _exceptionList = LookupQuery.ToList();

            return _exceptionList;
        }
    }


    IQueryable<IExceptionEntity> _query = null;
    public IQueryable<IExceptionEntity> LookupQuery
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(_query == null)
                _query = GetExceptionQuery(this.ExceptionCategory); 

            return _exceptionList;
        }
        set
    { this._query = value; }
    }



    private void InitializeExceptionQuery()
    {
        String whereClause = "Filters defined here from user control properties.";

        switch (this.ExceptionCategory)
        {
            case ExceptionCategories.Product:
                this.LookupQuery = base.Repository.GetFilteredQuery<ProductException>(this.LookupQuery, whereClause, this.SortField, this.SortDirection).Cast<IExceptionEntity>();
                break;
            case ExceptionCategories.Part:
                this.LookupQuery = base.Repository.GetFilteredQuery<PartException>(this.LookupQuery, whereClause, this.SortField, this.SortDirection).Cast<IExceptionEntity>();
                break;
            case ExceptionCategories.Rebuild:
                this.LookupQuery = base.Repository.GetFilteredQuery<RebuildException>(this.LookupQuery, whereClause, this.SortField, this.SortDirection).Cast<IExceptionEntity>();
                break;
            case ExceptionCategories.UNKNOWN:
                throw new ArgumentException("Exception Category is undefined");
        }
    }


    private void BindQueryResults()
    {

        switch (this.ExceptionCategory)
        {
            case ExceptionCategories.Product:
                listView.DataSource = this.ExceptionList.Cast<ProductException>();
                listView.DataBind(); 
                break;
            case ExceptionCategories.Part:
                listView.DataSource = this.ExceptionList.Cast<PartException>();
                listView.DataBind();
                break;
            case ExceptionCategories.Rebuild:
                listView.DataSource = this.ExceptionList.Cast<RebuildException>();
                listView.DataBind();
                break;
            case ExceptionCategories.UNKNOWN:
                throw new ArgumentException("Exception Category is undefined");
        }
    }
```

The whole goal is that I want to be able to call the ExceptionList property, cast it to one of the types that implement the IExceptionEntity interface and Voila! no matter which of the three entities I am querying there is a single point from which I can retreive results ... i.e. see BindQueryResults().

This, however is not the case. When I run this, the ExceptionList property is throwing an exception when it attempts to convert the Query to a list (.ToList())

```
Unable to cast the type 'PartException' to type 'IExceptionEntity'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

I thought that you could cast an Interface and the classes that implement it back and forth as neccessary. Clearly this is not the case and I suppose that it makes sense, but is there any other way to accomplish what I am attempting to do? I gotta believe that there is. Does anybody else have this same conundrum?

Thank you,
G

**UPDATE: 2013-01-22**

I am under the impression that if I derive from a base class instead of the interface, I will be able to cast the ExceptionList from the base class to the derived class and back again.

To this end I have been following HighCores suggestion. I have ...

- Created, in the conceptual model (EDMX), an Entity which contains all
  the properties shared between the three "Exception" Entities
  (ProductException, PartException, RebuildException). I named it
  "ExceptionBase"
- Deleted thos fields from the three exception extities and derived them from "ExceptionBase"

The problem I have now is that the mapping between each exception entity and it's underlying table is broken. I need to map the fields in the base class to the underlying table of the derived entities. I was expecting to be able to, in the Mapping Details window, select the Value/Property from the base class to map to the respective table column, however the only values that are available are those of the derived class and not those of the base class.

**UPDATE: 2013-01-23**

As it turns out the Conceptual Model I am using uses the TPT (Table Per Type strategy) which is the reason why implementing inheritence in this way will not work. The common fields would have to be split off into their own table in the database in order for me to inherit from them. Unfortunatley the database schema, however is unable to be altered.

I referenced the following articles which I hope someone may also find useful:

- [Implementing Inheritance with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC
  Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
- [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564972/how-to-implement-inheritance-table-per-type-in-entity-framework-4-3-via-code-fir)

So I am still looking for a way to accomplish this if anyone has any additional ideas I would welcome any further suggestions.

**UPDATE: 2013-01-23**

Thank you Matthew for your response! My table structures look like ...

*ProductException*

- ID [PK]
- ProductName
- **ExceptionMsg**
- **ExceptionSev**

*PartException*

- ID [PK]
- PartName
- PartManufacturer
- PartCost
- ProductID [FK]
- **ExceptionMsg**
- **ExceptionSev**

*RebuildException*

- ID [PK]
- RebuildReason
- RebuildManufacturer
- ProductID [FK]
- **ExceptionMsg**
- **ExceptionSev**

Basically I would want to create a BaseEntity with ExceptionMsg, ExceptionSev and ID(?) since these fields are shared by all three Exception Entities.

---

**NOTE:** Could whoever downvoted this post please provide an explanation? Downvoting is only useful if I can learn from the mistake so not to repeat it.

Comment: are you using EF code-first or EDMX? if EDMX, you can have a base entity type which will hold all common properties, instead of an interface extraneous to EF

Comment: @HighCore I am using EDMX. I had attempted to create a base class from which these three entities can derive, however, the EDMX creates the initial entities and they derive from the "EntityObject". When I attempt to derive the partial classes from another Base Class I get an error about deriving from multiple base classes. I cannot change what the EDMX creates either as I have about 50 other entities in the model that all derive from EntityObject.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. If you want to derive your entities from a base entity, in the EDMX you need to define this base entity and set it as the base class for the derived ones (IN the EDMX designer via properties). If you don't want to do it one by one, you can manually edit the EDMX file (it's an XML file)

Comment: Ohhh ... I was not aware that we could modify this. In the properties pane for the Entity in the "BaseType" dropdown I get a list of exiting entities but it will not allow me to enter in the BaseClass that I created nor does it appear in the list.

Comment: Please re-read my comment: if you want to derive your entities from a base entity, in the EDMX you need to define this base entity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23169/discussion-between-gary-o-stenstrom-and-highcore)

Comment: Can you post an example of your table structure and entities? I am having some trouble understanding exactly what the ask is without it. Are you implying that you have a single table with a discriminator column you can generate your classes from (Table - per - hierarchy). This really will affect only your mapping an the way EF loads / persists. You can still create and use your entities somewhat agnostic to the underlying approach.

Comment: Thank you Matthew. I have added the table structures to the OP.